# outer join on 3 tables with access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a syntax error with this code. Is it possible to have your help. I worked on it since few days and I can resolve my problem.

Here are the code:

```
    SELECT Area.org, Supervisors.NomSup, Supervisors.PrenomSup, Employees.NomEmp, 
    Employees.PrenomEmp, Employees.NoIdAlcanEmp, Competencies.CodeCompetencies, Competencies.CompetencyName, 
    LinkResultComp.AssNote, LinkResultComp.AssDate
    FROM ((((((Area 
    INNER JOIN Supervisors ON Area.IdArea = Supervisors.IdArea)
    INNER JOIN Employees ON Supervisors.IdSupervisor = Employees.IdSupervisor)
    INNER JOIN LinkProfilesEmployees ON Employees.IdEmp = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdEmp)
    INNER JOIN Profiles ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdProfiles)
    INNER JOIN LinkProfComp ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfComp.IdProfiles)
    INNER JOIN Competencies ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkProfComp.IdCompetencies)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies =   LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)) 
   WHERE Area.org LIKE "*20*" AND Competencies.CodeCompetencies LIKE "khse2010-05"
   ORDER BY Supervisors.NomSup, Employees.NomEmp;
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?  It doesn't look like the parens are balanced..

Comment: You have an unequal number of parentheses. Why are you not using the query design window to build the links?

Comment: Remove one of the parentheses after "LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies".

Comment: Try aliasing your tablenames as well e.g. 'Supervisors' As 'S', this would shrink down your statement and make it a little easier to read back.

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like there is an unnecessary extra `)` at the end - try this:

```
SELECT Area.org, 
       Supervisors.NomSup, 
       Supervisors.PrenomSup, 
       Employees.NomEmp, 
       Employees.PrenomEmp, 
       Employees.NoIdAlcanEmp, 
       Competencies.CodeCompetencies, 
       Competencies.CompetencyName, 
       LinkResultComp.AssNote, 
       LinkResultComp.AssDate
FROM ((((((
           Area INNER JOIN Supervisors ON Area.IdArea = Supervisors.IdArea
          )
          INNER JOIN Employees ON Supervisors.IdSupervisor = Employees.IdSupervisor
         )
         INNER JOIN LinkProfilesEmployees ON Employees.IdEmp = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdEmp
        )
        INNER JOIN Profiles ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdProfiles
       )
       INNER JOIN LinkProfComp ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfComp.IdProfiles
      )
      INNER JOIN Competencies ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkProfComp.IdCompetencies
     )
     LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)
WHERE Area.org LIKE '*20*' AND Competencies.CodeCompetencies LIKE 'khse2010-05'
ORDER BY Supervisors.NomSup, Employees.NomEmp;
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to add an ADD at the end. Look my code and thaks for your support: